# how to display a new root category except default category in magento

Tags: php, magento

In my website I have a default menu which always shows in the header part. Now I want to add another root category which will show up in a specific page(not all pages). I already created a new root category from magento admin but don't know how to show only this category in frontend. point that my new category id is '12' I tried

```
 <?php
      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
      $tree=$category->getTreeModel(); 
      $tree->load();
      $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
      $arr = array();
      if ($ids){ 
    foreach ($ids as $id){ 
     $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
     $cat->load($id);
    $arr[$id]=$cat->getName();
     } 
    }
 ?>
  <?php 
  $cat_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat_id,12, true, true);
$position=array();
$index=array();
foreach($collection as $key=>$cat) {
    array_push($index,$cat->getPosition());
}
asort($index);
echo '<ul class="jetmenu blue">';
$c=0;
foreach($index as $index_new){
foreach($collection as $cat){
    if( $index_new==$cat->getPosition())
    {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'" />'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
    $cat_id=$cat->getId();
    $subcategory_html=GetSubcategory($cat_id);
    echo $subcategory_html;
    echo '</li>'; 
    }
}
}
 ?> 
    </ul>
```

but this only shows the default category, not the other category.Please help.

[image]

Comment: For clarity: root categories are never displayed in the frontend. They have two functions: collecting all top-level categories for a scope and association with a scope.Create a new Category under the root category and put all category there in.

Comment: I already did that...but it shows only default category not the root category.

Comment: Could you list down your Category hierarchy ? Also how you differ root category and default category for your store ?

Comment: ok I am posting a sreenshot in the main question.

Comment: I see **Inner Category** is inside the Parent Category which is **Default Category** for your store,thus you have only single root category which is **Default Category**

Comment: no... inner category is outside the parent category...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the root category with all categories underneath it.

```
<?php

  $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12); // Put your root category ID here.
  $subcategories = $root_category->getChildren();
  foreach(explode(',',$subcategories) as $subcategory) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory);
        echo '<a href="'.$category->getURL() .'" />'.$category->getName().'</a><br/>';
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Where to add this code,even am facing the same problem,am new to magento,can i know the file name where to add this code